# Subquery into a LIKE condition mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-like

I'm trying to make a query based on the result of another query, the principal query is this:

```
    SELECT d.nombre, d.apellido,em.codigo, em.descripcion, d.iddocente, em.idequipoMulti 
        FROM docenteequipomulti dem 
         INNER JOIN docente d ON dem.docente_iddocente=d.iddocente 
         INNER JOIN equipomulti em ON dem.equipoMulti_idequipoMulti=em.idequipoMulti 
        WHERE 
dem.iddocenteEquipoMulti LIKE '%(subquery)%'
```

without the `where` it show me all the values, but I have to filter them by the value returned by the subquery.

This is the subquery:

`SELECT concat_ws ('-', m.numModulo, p.periodo) AS MPeriodo FROM modulos m INNER JOIN periodo p ON m.periodo_idperiodo=p.idperiodo WHERE m.estado=1`

That query always will get one value for example "1-2015", but I put the subquery into the "()" and didn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have some ids like this

1--1-2015--Eq1

1--1-2015--Eq2

2--1-2015--Eq3

1--2-2015--Eq1

The idea is to filter those ids that have "1-2015" no matter what else they have, so it has to show only the 3 rows, excluding the last one.

Comment: Just add modulos to the JOIN

Comment: the problem is that the idmodulos is not equal to the other id, for example, the dem.iddocenteEquipoMulti is: "1--1-2015--Eq1", an the value that I get with the subquery is: "1-2015" I have to compare if it is similar not equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't make work as I want it, instead I made the subquery, Save it into a variable and then use it as a parameter for the principal query, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

*Edited to meet the changed question*

You should include `modulos` in `JOIN` and filter in `JOIN ... ON`:

```
SELECT d.nombre, d.apellido,em.codigo, em.descripcion, d.iddocente, em.idequipoMulti 
    FROM docenteequipomulti dem 
     INNER JOIN docente d ON dem.docente_iddocente=d.iddocente 
     INNER JOIN equipomulti em ON dem.equipoMulti_idequipoMulti=em.idequipoMulti 
     JOIN modulos m ON (dem.iddocenteEquipoMulti LIKE concat('%',m.numModulo, '-', p.periodo,'%') AND m.estado=1)
     JOIN periodo p ON m.periodo_idperiodo=p.idperiodo;
```

Comment: What's the relationship, then?

Comment: in a table i show the values for the query, but the idea is that every certain time the idmodulos that its estate=1 will change, for example today the active is the first one, I mean "1-2015", tomorrow it could be "2-2015" the ids from dem.iddocenteEquipoMulti are made by a union of three values, three ids between them is the idmodulo so in my table(php) i show the rows I got by the query but as I said it can change so I have to filtrate by that id to be "similar" not equal

Comment: doesn't work dear friend, if I type in my initial query LIKE '%1-2015%' as an static value I get what I want... so the solution(I think) is to put the subquery into the  LIKE condition '%subquery%' so I got back to my initial question, how can I do that?

Comment: If your subquery returns more than one row, you don't - you use join instead. If it returns single row, then you use `CONCAT()`.